# Sending a CSV file for a client list from a database

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, csv

What can I improve about this code in order to be production-ready? I'm not worried about security but about errors that could occur.

What exceptions should I catch? I feel overwhelmed about exceptions because I feel that there are a lot of exceptions that one can consider.

What else should I do? Should I do unit testing for this?

The script first loads the client list from an SQL database, then takes the daily work quantity about pallet movements from a SQL database, after that it writes a .csv file with this data, and finally sends it through email.

```
import pyodbc
import csv
import smtplib
import os.path
from datetime import date, timedelta
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication


def load_clients():
    client_list = {}
    connection_string = f'*'
    query = """
          SELECT clifor.a1_codice_clifor, anacf.ragione_soc_fiscale
            FROM anacf anacf, clifor clifor
           WHERE (clifor.a1_ditta_codice=5)
             AND (clifor.a1_tipo_cli1_for2=1)
             AND
              (anacf.a1_codice_anagrafica_generale=clifor.a2_anagrafica_codice)
    """
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string, autocommit=True)
    with cnxn:
        cursor = cnxn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)
        while True:
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            if not row:
                break
            client_list[row[0]] = row[1]
    return client_list


def load_movements(clients):
    movement_list = []
    connection_string = f'*'
    query = """
          SELECT datadoc, cliente,
            SUM (@DECODE(tipodoc, 3 ,palletts)) AS inputs,
            SUM (@DECODE(tipodoc, 5 ,palletts)) AS outputs
              FROM docmagat
           WHERE ditta=5
             AND anno=2020
             AND tipodoc in (3,5)
             AND datadoc=SYSDATE-1
           GROUP BY 1,2
    """
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
    with cnxn:
        cursor = cnxn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)
        while True:
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            if not row:
                break
            inputs = 0 if row[2] is None else row[2]
            outputs = 0 if row[3] is None else row[3]
            movement_list.append(tuple(
                (clients[row[1]], inputs, outputs, inputs
                 + outputs)))
    return movement_list


def load_file(movements, yesterday, folder):
    filename = 'pallet_movements ' + yesterday + '.csv'
    full_path = os.path.join(folder, filename)
    with open(full_path, mode='w', newline='') as pallet_movements:
        movements_writer = csv.writer(pallet_movements,
                                           delimiter=';')
        movements_writer.writerow(['Day: ' + yesterday])
        movements_writer.writerow(['Company', 'inputs', 'outputs',
                                       'Total'])
        for movement in movements:
            movements_writer.writerow(movement)
    return filename


def send_email(filename, yesterday, folder):
    sender = "*"
    destination = "*"
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = 'Pallet movements ' + yesterday
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = destination
    message_text = 'Good morning,\n\nYou can find Pallet movements from\
                      day ' + yesterday + ' attached.\n\nGoodbye'
    msg.attach(MIMEText(message_text))
    full_path = os.path.join(folder, filename)
    attachment = MIMEApplication(open(full_path, 'rb').read())
    attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment',
                        filename=filename)
    msg.attach(attachment)
    try:
        with smtplib.SMTP('*', 587) as smtpObj:
            smtpObj.ehlo()
            smtpObj.starttls()
            smtpObj.login("*", "*")
            smtpObj.sendmail(sender, destination, msg.as_string())
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


def main():
    yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)
    yesterday = yesterday.strftime(f'%d-%m-%Y')
    local_folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    clients = load_clients()
    movements = load_movements(clients)
    filename = load_file(movements, yesterday, local_folder)
    send_email(filename, yesterday, local_folder)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that code works? Look `with smtplib.SMTP('*, 587) as smtpObj:` looks like it's missing an `'`.

Comment: Yes, it works. I deleted all the private information, that's why there are some * in place. I'll correct that typo. Thanks.

Comment: Does your company code everything in, what is it, Italian?

Comment: We don't code much. The last code written here was from 15 years ago. I came here a few months ago and I wanted to automate all the manual processes that I can.

Comment: Considering most users here won't be able to read Italian, could you tell us more about how the code works?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll rewrite it now.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review escarta. Thank you for translating the code. Your question would be easier to understand and review if you gave a short overview of what it does. E.g. "My code is a shop to buy pallets from. When you sign up in `foo` we will send you an email, through `bar`, that looks like …. Upon sending the email we add the user to the database through `baz` that adds to the table `UserTable` that has the following columns …."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Answers to your questions

> What can I improve about this code in order to be production-ready? I'm not worried about security but about errors that could occur.

So make a list of errors that you expect could occur, and think about what should happen in each case. For example, just looking at `main()`, I can think of:

- Loading clients fails
- Loading movements fails
- Creating the movement report file fails
- Sending the email fails

Is it important to know why something fails exactly? If so make it more specific. For example:

- Loading client fails:

  - Could not connect to the database
  - Could not run the query

What should happen if any of those errors occur in production? If you know the network is flaky, you could for example retry connecting to the database a few times before giving up. But if the query fails there is most likely not much you can do.

> What exceptions should I catch? I feel overwhelmed about exceptions because I feel that there are a lot of exceptions that one can consider.

There are many places where exceptions can be thrown, and besides exceptions there are also function that do not throw an exception but just return a value that indicates that an error occurred. The advantage of exceptions is that if you don't catch them, the program will abort instead of doing something unexpected.

As the name implies, exceptions are normally used to signal that something unexpected has happened. If the system runs out of memory, or it fails to open a file that you expect to exist, there is most likely not much you can do at that point, and letting the program abort is the right thing to do. However, there are situations where you can do better than that. It is up to you to decide what exceptions would be beneficial to catch.

Another nice thing about exceptions is that you do not have to catch them in the same function as the exception is generated. So you don't necessarily have to add exception handling all over the place, but you can defer it to a function higher up the call stack.

The code you showed looks like it does a one-off operation, loading some data, and generating a single email based on the data. You could decide to just not handle exceptions at all, and then if any error occurred, the email would just not be sent. But you could do a bit better than that: handle exceptions from all database access and file loading, and in the exception handler send an email notifying the recipient that an error occurred and that there is no list of pallet movements available today due to an error. Alternatively, you could send a notification to a technician so they can investigate why the code failed. Handling this would look like so:

```
def main():
    try:
        yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)
        yesterday = yesterday.strftime(f'%d-%m-%Y')
        local_folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        clients = load_clients()
        movements = load_movements(clients)
        filename = load_file(movements, yesterday, local_folder)
    except:
        send_error_email()
        raise # Causes the program to abort anyway

    send_email(filename, yesterday, local_folder)
```

I think that's more useful than just printing the exception and exitting the program normally. For example, if your program is run as a cron job, then handling the exception in `send_email()` like you did would just hide errors.

> What else should I do? Should I do unit testing for this?

Yes, you should test your code, regardless of whether you handle exceptions or not. Your test cases should test whether the code performs as required in all the scenarios you expect can happen. It's perfectly fine to not handle exceptions if the requirement is that your code just aborts in case of any error.

## Give `load_file()` a better name

The function `load_file()` does not load a file like its name implies, but rather creates a new file. The name `create_file()` would already be better. But it is still quite generic. What kind of file does it generate? Maybe `create_movement_report()` would be even better.

Comment: Logging the exception might be good--in case the error email can't be sent.